# Clicking an IE website button

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm having trouble trying to get my code to click a button after entering the load numbers into the website's text box. I keep getting an

> error 91

on the line `.all("btn btn-primary").Click`

The button's code from the website:

```
<div class="submit-section">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-ng-disabled="vm.loadingTracking">
                        <!-- ngIf: !vm.loadingTracking --><span class="ng-scope" data-ng-if="!vm.loadingTracking">Track shipments</span><!-- end ngIf: !vm.loadingTracking -->
                        <!-- ngIf: vm.loadingTracking -->
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Code that I have:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim loadNumberCells As Range
Dim traceNumbers As String
Dim resultsDiv As HTMLDivElement
Dim resultsTable As htmltable, infoTable As htmltable
Dim infoTables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim ProNumber As String, ProNumberRow As Variant

'Get pickup numbers from column A in 1st sheet starting at A2

With Worksheets(1)
    Set loadNumberCells = .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With
loadNumberCells.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
traceNumbers = Join(Application.Transpose(loadNumberCells), vbNewLine)

URL = "https://arcb.com/tools/tracking.html"

'Get existing IE window open at page, if any

'Set IE = Get_IE_Window2(URL)
If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = True
    'SetForegroundWindow .Hwnd
    .navigate URL
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTMLdoc = .Document
End With

With HTMLdoc
    'Put trace numbers in input box and click Trace
    .all("trackingNumbers").Value = traceNumbers
    .all("btn btn-primary").Click
    While .ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
End With

IE.Visible = True
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(0).click`

Comment: Check if there is some `iFrame`, if there is, you will have to change your code.

Comment: the `HTMLdoc.all("btn btn-primary")` returns an array of objects. it may have only one element, but it is still an array, so you have to refer to it in the way that @omegastripes commented.